# gsoap and SSL/TLS vs .Net Web Services

Tags: web-services, asmx, gsoap

Does gSOAP provides SSL/TLS, VPN, encryption, digital signing of data? What to prefer for web service security, gsoap or .Net for previous mentioned properties.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, gSOAP supports ssl/https by using openssl, the info can be found from http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.21.

About which to choose, gSOAP or .NET, i think that should depend on the project and be different case by case. For these two, at least gSOAP is corss-platform while .NET is only on Windows.